# How to solve the narrowing proxy warning when using SINGLE_TABLE Inheritance strategy in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-initialization

We have structure something like bellow:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        BaseEntity that = (BaseEntity) o;
        if (getId() != null ? !getId().equals(that.getId()) : that.getId() != null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "BASE_ORGANIZATION")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "disc")
@DiscriminatorValue("baseOrganization")
public class BaseOrganization extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "BASE_PERSONNEL")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "disc")
@DiscriminatorValue("basePersonnel")
public class BasePersonnel extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BASE_ORGANIZATION_ID")
    private BaseOrganization baseOrganization;
}
```

`BaseEntity`, `BasePersonnel` and `BaseOrganization` is in **core_project** that all projects can used these objects. Now we create a project that depended to core_project. We must to extends `BasePeronnel` and `BaseOrganization` based on our business context. For this reason we added some classes in our project like bellow:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("organization")
public class Organization extends BaseOrganization {

    @Column(name = "MISSION_Type")
    private String missionType;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("personnel")
public class Personnel extends BasePersonnel {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MISSION_ORGANIZATION_ID")
    private Organization missionOrganization;
}
```

Our problem is raised, when we wanna to get all personnel. When we called `getAllPersonnel` method in `PersonnelRepository`, hibernate logged bellow message:

```
WARN  o.h.e.i.StatefulPersistenceContext - HHH000179: Narrowing proxy to class org.xyz.organization.Organization - this operation breaks ==
```

After that, when we see `List<Personnel>` object, `missionOrganization` property is `null`, but `baseOrganization` property in super class is loaded!

We think when tow class that have SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy, hibernate `LazyInitializer` can not detect correct concrete class.

Also we debugged `narrowProxy` method in `StatefulPersistenceContext` class and we understood that `concreteProxyClass.isInstance(proxy)` returned `false`. because `proxy` object have `BaseOrganization` object in `LazyInitializer` and `concreteProxyClass` refer to `Organization` class!

Comment: Note. We created a new class (`Deposit extends BaseEntity`). this class did not had SINGLE_TABLE strategy. we added `private Organization organization;` property. after that when we called `getAll` method from `DepositRepository`, all data without any problem returned (everything was OK)!

Comment: is link [ https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/1655 ] related to this topic?